# Why does my terminal require pressing the up key twice to move backwards in history?

Tags: terminal

If I press `up` or `down` in terminal, be it `xterm`, a virtual console or `kitty`, without any custom `bashrc` or `inputrc`, via ssh or locally:

After a return, the next line in my history is shown, but otherwise it takes two presses to show the next item.

This also occures with k and j, mapped via readline to history-search-backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The problem was there was no problem. History search was working as expected. It was just searching a history where every item was duplicated. This was some code in my bashrc that had been synced across to the ssh server too.

Moral of the story: check assumptions, check the files you think you're reading